# Как настроить соединение между windows 10 и виртуальной машиной (virtualbox) с ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

Пинг с виртуальной машины (Ubuntu 16.04) на Windows проходит нормально, а вот обратно (ping 192.168.56.101 из Windows) не работает.
Когда была на ВМ была Ubuntu 14.04, то все было ОК.
Подскажите, что делаю не так?
[image]

Comment: Это больше на какой то фаервол похоже, если только в одну сторону. посмотрите iptables